# Issue with calculating the cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I am trying to calculate the cholesky decomposition of the matrix Q=

```
2 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0
-1 3 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0
0 -1 2 0 0 -1 0 0 0
-1 0 0  3 -1 0 -1 0 0 
0 -1 0 -1 4 -1 0 -1 0
0 0 -1 0 -1 3 0 0 -1
0 0 0 -1 0 0 2 -1 0
0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 3 -1
0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 2
```

But it says that the matrix should be positive definite. The inverse of the matrix does exist. Actually the above is a precision matrix. Any suggestions

Comment: What software are you using for your Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: What software are you using for your matrix-inversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $v=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)^T$. Then $Q v = 0$, just by looking at the matrix above.

This is not positive definite or invertible. No Matlab necessary.

Comment: OK, I used Octave :-).

Answer (score 2):

I get the cholesky-factor ***C*** by the LDU-decomposition as $\small C=L\cdot D$ with

$$ \small \text{L=}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\  -1/2&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\  0&-2/5&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\  -1/2&-1/5&-1/8&1&0&0&0&0&0\\  0&-2/5&-1/4&-10/19&1&0&0&0&0\\  0&0&-5/8&-1/19&-25/54&1&0&0&0\\  0&0&0&-8/19&-5/27&-16/95&1&0&0\\  0&0&0&0&-19/54&-5/19&-15/17&1&0\\  0&0&0&0&0&-54/95&-2/17&-1&1 \end{bmatrix} $$

and the diagonalmatrix ***D*** with
$$ \small  \text{diag(D)=} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}&\sqrt{5/2}&\sqrt{8/5}&\sqrt{19/8}&\sqrt{54/19}&\sqrt{95/54}&\sqrt{136/95}&\sqrt{24/17}& 0 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Numerically to two dec digits this is

$$ \small \text{ C =} \begin{bmatrix}  
    1.41&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
   -0.71&    1.58&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
    0.00&   -0.63&    1.26&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
   -0.71&   -0.32&   -0.16&    1.54&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
    0.00&   -0.63&   -0.32&   -0.81&    1.69&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
    0.00&    0.00&   -0.79&   -0.08&   -0.78&    1.33&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00\\
    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&   -0.65&   -0.31&   -0.22&    1.20&    0.00&    0.00\\
    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&   -0.59&   -0.35&   -1.06&    1.19&    0.00\\
    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&    0.00&   -0.75&   -0.14&   -1.19&    0.00
     \end{bmatrix}$$
The right-down entry is zero by the LDU-decomposition, so the matrix ***Q*** is only positive semidefinite( one eigenvalue is zero). Some software-cholesky-procedures might not be able to deal with close-to-zero or zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Checking the singular value decomposition (or eigendecomposition, since the matrix is symmetric after all) reveals that the matrix is in fact singular. Most Cholesky routines are ill-equipped to handle the positive semidefinite case, which is what OP's problem might be.